# How to open a PDF file included in assets folder in Ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Is it possible to add a PDF file in the assets folder and then access it within the Ionic 2 application.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do that.

1. InAppBrowser
2. Themeable Browser
3. Sitewearts Document viewer
4. Android Native PDF Viewer

You can find the cordova plugins for all the above situations. Please read below article to see more info.

[**Opening PDF Files In Ionic 2**](https://bendyworks.com/blog/The-Not-At-All-Definitive-Guide-To-Opening-PDF-Files-In-Ionic-2)

Git repo: [**PDFExample**](https://github.com/TheCorbin/PDFExample)

Comment: Hi using these methods we can download an online pdf and save that and later open it. My requirement is to add the PDF inside the application folder. As soon as you install the app, the PDF will be available in it. No online interactions

Comment: @sampath i am trying to use inappbrowser using ionic but i am not able to get the pdf i am getting blank white screen please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427319/how-to-open-an-local-pdf-using-inappbrowser/44429700#44429700

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works for me.

Its need a plugin.

```
showDocument(){
    const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
        title: 'My PDF'
    }
    const imgeLocation = `${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}www/assets/imgs/${'Jainbhajan-Jeevan-Saar-By-Nirmal-Gangwal-1-ilovepdf-compressed (1).pdf'}`;
    this.document.viewDocument(imgeLocation, 'application/pdf', options)
}
```