# How to open an local pdf using InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic2, filepath, inappbrowser, ionic3

I have downloaded an pdf file from the server using [Transfer Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/) and i am trying to open the file using InAppBrower plugin i am not getting anything. i mean nothing is happening.

```
fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + file.filename,false,{
        headers: {
            'authorization': 'bearer xxxx'
        }
    }).then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
      console.log(entry.nativeURL);
      const browser = this.iab.create(entry.nativeURL, '_system', 'location=yes'); //here the inappbrowser plugin code.
    }, (error) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
      console.log('ERROR');
    });
```

> my console.log(entry.nativeURL); prints this path `file:///data/user/0/com.schneider.and/files/Attendance_Policy_Ver_1.0.pdf`

Comment: check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304729/not-able-to-launch-a-pdf-file-in-inappbrowser-in-android

Comment: after trying the above stack answer i am getting white page displayed in my inappbrowser  any idea @SaEChowdary

Comment: Where are you testing it?

Comment: i am test in my real device @Sampath

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the nativeUrl in the browserURL and see if you could jump to the exact .pdf....

Then try

```html
fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + file.filename,false,{
        headers: {
            'authorization': 'bearer xxxx'
        }
    }).then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
      console.log(entry.nativeURL);
      let browser=new InApp Browser(entry.nativeURL,'_blank');
    }, (error) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
      console.log('ERROR');
    });
```

And import InAppBrowser from  'ionic-native'

```html
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';
```

Comment: i am getting blank screen even after trying the above answer

Comment: ok...did you try pasting the link in browser's URLbar? If yes then what did you get? And are you able to run the same in chrome developer tools?

Comment: the link in the browser url bar will not show the pdf because it needs headers object if you see in my above question i have given authorization for downloading the file so my file is in the path that i have mentioned in my question using that path only i have to open in inappbrowser

Comment: When you're running the app, then what URL are you getting in the URLbar?

Comment: same url that you see on my question

Answer (score 0):

i use this code and its works for me

```
showDocument(){
      const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
        title: 'My PDF'
      }
      const imgeLocation = `${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}www/assets/imgs/${'Jainbhajan-Jeevan-Saar-By-Nirmal-Gangwal-1-ilovepdf-compressed (1).pdf'}`;
      this.document.viewDocument(imgeLocation, 'application/pdf', options)
    }
```